# Fill an arrow head with TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, arrows, tikz-arrows

I would like to fill an arrow head with a color, but I have a problem with the `fill` command :

[image]

My code is :

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\def \dx{10}
\def \dy{5}
\def \dz{5}

\draw  (0,\dy/4,\dz/2)--++(\dx/8,0,0)--++(0,1,0)[-open triangle 60 reversed];
\draw  (0,-\dy/4,\dz/2)--++(\dx/8,0,0)--++(0,1,0)[-open triangle 60 reversed, fill=blue];

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

but it's not working ... Any clue ?

**EDIT :**

I have modified my code to use the new library `arrows.meta` but there is a problem with specific arrow heads like reversed triangle to fill it with a color :

[image]

The code :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}

\tikzset{
    antenne/.style={
        -{open triangle 60 reversed[fill=blue]}
                },
    ronde/.style={
        -{Circle[fill=blue]}
                },
        }

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[antenne] (0,0) -- (2,0) -- (2,2) ;
    \draw[ronde] (5,0) -- (7,0) -- (7,2) ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**RE-EDIT :**

I found the problem, to fill the arrow head I had to replace `open triangle 60 reversed[fill=blue]` by `triangle 60 reversed[fill=blue]`, the open prevents TikZ from filling the head with a color.

[image]

Comment: Maybe worth a look: [Why schuld the minimal class be avoided?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/42114/4918) …

Comment: @Tobi Thanks for the tips, I have modified the document class to article

Comment: @dcmst Thanks for the link, I will take a look, that's the first time I encounter the TikZ library "arrows.meta".

Comment: It has been introduced in PGF version 3.00, which is not part of TeXLive 2013. On the other hand there is also a solution that does not require PGF 3.00